# Expectation of 3^x, where X~Binomial(10000,0.5)

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution

> Suppose that $X\sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$, where $n = 10000$ and $p = 0.5$
>
> What is $E(3^X)$?

I know that $E(3^X) = 2^{10000}$, but I have no clue how to prove this. And in fact, through trial and error, it seems that $E(3^X) = 2^n$.

How would one reduce this thing into $2^{10000}$:

$$E(3^x) = \sum_{i=0}^{10000} 3^i(0.5)^{10000}{10000 \choose i}$$

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? It evaluates to $(0.5)^{10000}\times (1+3)^{10000}=2^{10000}$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas oh yes, i see it now! thanks!

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n3^i(0.5)^{1000}\binom{n}{i}&=(0.5)^n\sum_{i=0}^n3^i\binom{n}{i}\\
&=(0.5)^n\sum_{i=0}^n3^i\cdot 1^{n-i}\cdot \binom{n}{i}\\
&=(0.5)^n (3+1)^n\\
&=2^n
\end{align}

where I have used $(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^na^ib^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}$